How to add Alpha in background?
I want to change background alpha rgba(0,0,0,.5), in angular material-18, i tried this code but not working:
.alternate-theme-blue-navbar {
  .mat-toolbar-row {
    background: rgba(mat.get-theme-color(m3-blue-theme.$light-theme, primary), .8) !important;
    color: var(--mat-toolbar-container-text-color);
  }
}

Please help.

issue not reproducible stackblitz

Your question is very confusing. Do you want the toolbar to be blue (primary color), or gray? What is the code for your template? Do you have a multi-row toolbar? If not, the .mat-toolbar-row element doesn't even exist.

Since no minimal reproducible example provided, here is a working example using different alpha values for each toolbar row.
styles.scss
.alternate-theme-blue-navbar {
  .mat-toolbar-row:nth-child(1) {
    background: rgba(mat.get-theme-color($theme, primary), 0.8) !important;
    color: var(--mat-toolbar-container-text-color);
  }
  .mat-toolbar-row:nth-child(2) {
    background: rgba(mat.get-theme-color($theme, primary), 0.5) !important;
    color: var(--mat-toolbar-container-text-color);
  }
  .mat-toolbar-row:nth-child(3) {
    background: rgba(mat.get-theme-color($theme, primary), 0.1) !important;
    color: var(--mat-toolbar-container-text-color);
  }
}

HTML:
<mat-toolbar class="alternate-theme-blue-navbar">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>Custom Toolbar</span>
  </mat-toolbar-row>

  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>Second Line</span>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <mat-icon
      class="example-icon"
      aria-hidden="false"
      aria-label="Example user verified icon"
      >verified_user</mat-icon
    >
  </mat-toolbar-row>

  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>Third Line</span>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <mat-icon
      class="example-icon"
      aria-hidden="false"
      aria-label="Example heart icon"
      >favorite</mat-icon
    >
    <mat-icon
      class="example-icon"
      aria-hidden="false"
      aria-label="Example delete icon"
      >delete</mat-icon
    >
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>

Stackblitz Demo
